# allowed domains/subdomains in Uri

Tags: c#, url, uri

I have some url in Uri. How can i check if this url is part of some domain or subdomain.

Example:

URL:

```
http://www.example.com/something/index.apsx?lala=ddsadasd&dasdas=dsdas&dsdsd=ikpi&das=asd
```

allowed:

```
http://www.example.com/something/
```

not aloowed:

```
http://www.example.com/some/
```

if URL is in allowed domain then code continue executing.

Comment: Please add several allowed/not allowed scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.example.com/folder/page.ext?foo=bar");
uri.Segments.Contains("folder"); // true
uri.DnsSafeHost.Split('.').Contains("example"); // true
```

`uri.Segements` are:

- "/"
- "something/"
- "index.ext"

and `DnsSafeHost.Split('.')` are:

- www
- example
- com

so you can manipulate with this data as you want.

Edit:

```
uri.Segments.Any(s => String.Equals(s.Replace("/", String.Empty), "something", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
uri.DnsSafeHost.Split('.').Any(s => String.Equals(s, "example", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: if the target domain you are trying to match is mybank.com, wouldn't this match hahastealyourmoney.com/mybank.com?

Comment: an edit for an edit
but uri.DnsSafeHost.Split('.').Contains("example") would also match example.stealmymoney.com perhaps just check that DnsSafeHost ends with the proper domain.